# Set delegate to self in a subview. Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

Yes. I have a `UIViewController` called `NavigatorViewController`. This is a custom navigation structure which includes different "slots" where I can add content and swipe between these - this is not important for the actual problem, but just so you get the code.
"Slot" number 4 is added in the `NavigatorViewController` like this:

```
slot4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view4"];
slot4.view.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth*2, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
[self.view addSubview:slot4.view];
```

which works fine. I see the `UIViewController` (`view4`) that I added in the storyboard on the right spot.

Inside this slot4 UIViewController I want to add another subview. Another UIViewController called `ChatViewController`. I add it with these lines:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ChatViewController *viewController = (ChatViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Chat"];
viewController.view.tag = 266;
[slot4.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

So far so good - it also works fine. BUT..

My problem is that inside the ChatViewController there is a UITextView called `chatTextView`. I have set this:

```
@interface ChatViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> (...)
```

in the `ChatViewController` header, because I want to get the action from `chatTextView`. So fx. when the `chatTextView` "becomes firstResponder", it will call some kind of action. To make that happen I have to set

```
chatTextView.delegate = self;
```

inside the `ChatViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

But when I run the project and click on the `chatTextView`, it crashes. 
I get an error message saying:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xXXXXXXXXX)
```

When I set the `chatTextView`'s delegate to `nil` there's no errors, but then I cannot use it :-)

Please ask if I forgot something!

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of just adding `ChatViewController` view as subview try this,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ChatViewController *viewController = (ChatViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Chat"];
viewController.view.tag = 266;
[slot4 addChildViewController:viewController];                 
[slot4.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:slot4];
```

use the same approach for adding slot4 like,

```
slot4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view4"];
slot4.view.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth*2, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
[self addChildViewController:slot4];                 
[self.view addSubview:slot4.view];
[slot4 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```